# Use ramdajs for iterative calculations

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am trying to wrap my head over Ramda and functional programming in general and see if it makes sense in my case.

Below it the typical problem I need to solve:

**As input data, the following:**

```
const values = [
 { a: 1,   b: 2,   c: 3 },
 { a: 10,  b: 20,  c: 30 },
 ...
 { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 }
]
```

**The following functions are applied on the data:**

```
const eFn = x => x.a + x.b
const fFn = ? // cumulative add: Sum of the e keys from first to current index, first iteration f = 3, then 3 + 30, then 3 + 30 +300
const gFN = x => x.f > x.e
```

In this given sequence:

1. eFn()
2. fFn()
3. gFn()

**And the result is as follow:**

```
const results = [
 { a: 1,   b: 2,   c: 3,   e: 3,   f: 3,  g: true },
 { a: 10,  b: 20,  c: 30,  e: 30,  f: 33, g: true  },
 ...
 { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300, e: 300, f: 333, g: false }
]
```

**Question:**

For this type of problem,

- does it makes sense to use ramda?
- does it simplify the problem and can I avoid looping several time over the data knowing that fFn depends on the data of the previous rows and that gFn must be applied after fFn ?

I found it difficult to solve this problem in a nice way using Ramda.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

## Update (2019-02-12)

Based on the @scott-sauyet answer , I did try to benchmark Ramda vs Rambda.
As I was unale to replicate 100% his test, I modify it to change the behaviour of fFn and manually set-up the number of times to apply each functions.

```
    const {floor, random} = Math

    const demo = counts => {

      const eFns = R.curry((n, x) => R.assoc(`e${n}`, x.a + x.b, x))
      const fFns = R.curry((n, x) => R.assoc(`f${n}`,  x.d * x.b, x))
      const gFns = R.curry((n, x) => R.assoc(`g${n}`,  x.f > x.e, x))

      const transform = R.pipe(
        R.map(eFns(1)),
        R.map(eFns(2)),
        R.map(eFns(3)),
        R.map(eFns(4)),
        R.map(eFns(5)),
        R.map(eFns(6)),
        R.map(eFns(7)),
        R.map(eFns(8)),
        R.map(eFns(9)),
        R.map(eFns(10)),
        R.map(eFns(12)),
        R.map(eFns(13)),
        R.map(eFns(14)),
        R.map(eFns(15)),
        R.map(eFns(16)),
        R.map(eFns(17)),
        R.map(eFns(18)),
        R.map(eFns(19)),
        R.map(eFns(20)),
        R.map(eFns(21)),
        R.map(eFns(22)),
        R.map(eFns(23)),
        R.map(eFns(24)),
        R.map(eFns(25)),
        R.map(eFns(26)),
        R.map(eFns(27)),
        R.map(eFns(28)),
        R.map(eFns(29)),
        R.map(eFns(30)),
        R.map(eFns(31)),
        R.map(eFns(32)),
        R.map(eFns(33)),
        R.map(eFns(34)),
        R.map(eFns(35)),
        R.map(eFns(36)),
        R.map(eFns(37)),
        R.map(eFns(38)),
        R.map(eFns(39)),
        R.map(eFns(40)),
        R.map(fFns(1)),
        R.map(fFns(2)),
        R.map(fFns(3)),
        R.map(fFns(4)),
        R.map(fFns(5)),
        R.map(fFns(6)),
        R.map(fFns(7)),
        R.map(fFns(8)),
        R.map(fFns(9)),
        R.map(fFns(10)),
        R.map(gFns(1)),
        R.map(gFns(2)),
        R.map(gFns(3)),
        R.map(gFns(4)),
        R.map(gFns(5)),
        R.map(gFns(6)),
        R.map(gFns(7)),
        R.map(gFns(8)),
        R.map(gFns(9)),
        R.map(gFns(10))
      )


      const vals = R.times(n => ({
        a: floor(random() * 1000),
        b: floor(random() * 1000),
        c: floor(random() * 1000),
        d: floor(random() * 1000)
      }), counts)

      const now = new Date()
      transform(vals)
      const time = new Date() - now

      console.log(`Ran ${counts} records through ${eFns.length} e's, ${fFns.length} f's, and ${gFns.length} g's in ${time} ms`)
    }

    console.clear()
    demo(10)
    demo(100)
    demo(1000)
    demo(10000)
    demo(100000)
```

Now, I pasted this code successivley to [Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/) and then [Rambda REPL](https://rambda.now.sh/). I ran the test on windows 7, on a core i7-6820HQ with Chrome 66 and in Node.js v8.11.1.

To my surprise Rambda is slower than Ramda for my case. Please note that it's a quick and dirty test and I may have missed the proper way to set-up the test for Rambda (I just wanted to copy and paste the code in each REPL and run in node by modifying the import statement).

Here are my results:
(Note that the graph is in Log-Log scale)

```
Record Number             [-] :  10 | 10 | 1000 | 10000  | 10000
Ramda Chrome 66  [time in ms] :  5  | 39 | 329  | 3673   | 38910  
Rambda Chrome 66 [time in ms] :  6  | 85 | 530  | 5306   | 53777  
Ramda Node.js    [time in ms] :  8  | 38 | 396  | 4219   | 45621
Rambda Node.js   [time in ms] :  7  | 62 | 537  | 5468   | 57540
```

[image: Log-Log plot of Ramda vs Rambda]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might make sense to use Ramda.  Note that the sweet spot for Ramda is a sequence of simple transformations `pipe`'d or `compose`'d together to create a more complex one.  So the most straightforward way to use Ramda does not meet your goal of looping only once.  Transducers might help with this in some cases, but many Ramda functions are not transducer-ready, so you'd have to see what would work.

But I would argue that the right way to code a problem like this is to start with the simple code and only fix performance problems if you actually have them.  Write the simple code and if it turns out to be a bottleneck in your application, then address it.  (And only do so after you've addressed any worse bottlenecks.)  Surprisingly often it turns out that code you thought would be a problem is not one at all.

So I might do this problem something like this:

```js
const {assoc, curry, tail, scan, pipe, map} = R

const eFn = x => assoc('e', x.a + x.b, x)
const fFn = (a, x) => assoc('f', a.f + x.e, x)
const gFn = x => assoc('g', x.f > x.e, x)

// scan includes initial value -- should this be fixed?
const myScan = curry((fn, init, xs) => tail(scan(fn, init, xs)))

const transform = pipe(
  map(eFn),
  myScan(fFn, {f: 0}),
  map(gFn)  
)

const values = [
 { a: 1,   b: 2,   c: 3 },
 { a: 10,  b: 20,  c: 30 },
 { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 }
]

console.log(transform(values))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

This shows something of a flaw in `scan` (similar to `mapAccum`, but with a simpler interface).  `scan(add, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4]) //=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`.  I can't see a good reason that the results should include that initial `0`, although I haven't gone to check the history to see if I'm missing something important.  I get around this by wrapping it in a function which follows it by `tail`.  But we could just as easily add `tail` to the pipeline:

```
const transform = pipe(
  map(eFn),
  scan(fFn, {f: 0}), 
  tail,
  map(gFn)  
)
```

### Update

A comment asked about performance.  Here is a version that tests many `e`, `f`, and `g` style functions for a given number of records:

```js
const {curry, tail, scan, map, assoc, range, apply, pipe, addIndex, times} = R
const {floor, random} = Math
const myScan = curry((fn, init, xs) => tail(scan(fn, init, xs)))

const demo = (es, fs, gs, counts) => {

  const eFns = map(n => (x) => assoc(`e${n}`, x.a + x.b, x), range(1, es + 1))
  const fFns = map(n => (a, x) => assoc(`f${n}`, a[`f${n}`] + x[`e${n}`], x), range(1, fs + 1))
  const gFns = map(n => (x) => assoc(`g${n}`, x[`f${n}`] > x[`e${n}`], x), range(1, gs + 1))

  const transform = apply(pipe)([...map(map, eFns), ...addIndex(map)((f, i) => myScan(f, {[`f${i + 1}`]: 0}), fFns), ...map(map, gFns)])

  const vals = times(n => ({
    a: floor(random() * 1000),
    b: floor(random() * 1000),
    c: floor(random() * 1000),
  }), counts)

  const now = new Date()
  transform(vals)
  const time = new Date() - now

  console.log(`Ran ${counts} records through ${eFns.length} e's, ${fFns.length} f's, and ${gFns.length} g's in ${time} ms`)
}

console.clear()
demo(40, 10, 10, 100)
demo(40, 10, 10, 1000)
demo(40, 10, 10, 10000)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

For 10000 records with 40 e's, 10 f's, and 10 g's, I get times around 2.5 seconds in Chrome on a newish MacBook Pro.  I don't know if this is reasonable for your application.  (You can also play around with this on the **[Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20%7Bfloor%2C%20random%7D%20%3D%20Math%3B%0Aconst%20myScan%20%3D%20curry%28%28fn%2C%20init%2C%20xs%29%20%3D%3E%20tail%28scan%28fn%2C%20init%2C%20xs%29%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20demo%20%3D%20%28es%2C%20fs%2C%20gs%2C%20counts%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20const%20eFns%20%3D%20map%28n%20%3D%3E%20%28x%29%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%60e%24%7Bn%7D%60%2C%20x.a%20%2B%20x.b%2C%20x%29%2C%20range%281%2C%20es%20%2B%201%29%29%0A%20%20const%20fFns%20%3D%20map%28n%20%3D%3E%20%28a%2C%20x%29%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%60f%24%7Bn%7D%60%2C%20a%5B%60f%24%7Bn%7D%60%5D%20%2B%20x%5B%60e%24%7Bn%7D%60%5D%2C%20x%29%2C%20range%281%2C%20fs%20%2B%201%29%29%0A%20%20const%20gFns%20%3D%20map%28n%20%3D%3E%20%28x%29%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%60g%24%7Bn%7D%60%2C%20x%5B%60f%24%7Bn%7D%60%5D%20%3E%20x%5B%60e%24%7Bn%7D%60%5D%2C%20x%29%2C%20range%281%2C%20gs%20%2B%201%29%29%0A%0A%20%20const%20transform%20%3D%20apply%28pipe%29%28%5B...map%28map%2C%20eFns%29%2C%20...addIndex%28map%29%28%28f%2C%20i%29%20%3D%3E%20myScan%28f%2C%20%7B%5B%60f%24%7Bi%20%2B%201%7D%60%5D%3A%200%7D%29%2C%20fFns%29%2C%20...map%28map%2C%20gFns%29%5D%29%0A%0A%20%20const%20vals%20%3D%20times%28n%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20floor%28random%28%29%20%2A%201000%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20floor%28random%28%29%20%2A%201000%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20floor%28random%28%29%20%2A%201000%29%2C%0A%20%20%7D%29%2C%20counts%29%0A%0A%20%20const%20now%20%3D%20new%20Date%28%29%0A%20%20transform%28vals%29%0A%20%20const%20time%20%3D%20new%20Date%28%29%20-%20now%0A%0A%20%20console.log%28%60Ran%20%24%7Bcounts%7D%20records%20through%20%24%7BeFns.length%7D%20e%27s%2C%20%24%7BfFns.length%7D%20f%27s%2C%20and%20%24%7BgFns.length%7D%20g%27s%20in%20%24%7Btime%7D%20ms%60%29%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%0A%0Ademo%2840%2C%2010%2C%2010%2C%20100%29%0Ademo%2840%2C%2010%2C%2010%2C%201000%29%0Ademo%2840%2C%2010%2C%2010%2C%2010000%29%0A)**.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even-though it involves more loops (well looping every time), this is quite readable. I have to evaluate the cost in term of performance, as in my App, there are something like 50 functions like `eFn` and maybe 10 like `fFn` and that will require as many loops over an array of 10000 elements. Maybe the performance will be acceptable. I also see that library like [Rambda](https://github.com/selfrefactor/rambda) should out-perform ramda.

Comment: I haven't paid much attention to `Rambda`, but I know that such is their claim.  It might well be true, as they try to do less.  I've updated to include some performance numbers.  For 10000 random records, with 40 `eFn`s, 10 `fFn`s, and 10 `gFns`, I get times around 2.5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will adapt your code and see how Rambda.js performs compare to Ramda for this case. I'll post this as a new reply this week. While technically the proposed answer from @customcommander avoids extra loop over the input data, I found your solution more readable when there is multiple functions to apply as it is for my case. Thanks both of you for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes sense to use Ramda:

1. Ramda does not mutate data
2. Ramda does have lots of functions to help you deal with lists and objects

This would mutate the original object:

```
const add_ab = obj => { obj.e = obj.a + obj.b; return obj };
```

Whereas this wouldn't:

```
const add_ab = obj => assoc('e', obj.a + obj.b, obj);
```

You can combine iterating **and** accumulating values with [`mapAccum`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mapAccum) which may be useful in your case:

> The mapAccum function behaves like a combination of map and reduce; it applies a function to each element of a list, passing an accumulating parameter from left to right, and returning a final value of this accumulator together with the new list.
>
> The iterator function receives two arguments, acc and value, and should return a tuple [acc, value].

```js
const {assoc, compose, last, mapAccum} = R;

const data = [
 { a: 1,   b: 2,   c: 3 },
 { a: 10,  b: 20,  c: 30 },
 { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 }
];


const set_e = obj => assoc('e', obj.a + obj.b, obj);
const set_f = (acc, obj) =>  assoc('f', acc.f + obj.e, obj);
const set_g = obj => assoc('g', obj.f > obj.e, obj);

const execute = compose(last, mapAccum((acc, cur) => [
  set_f(acc, set_e(cur)),
  set_g(set_f(acc, set_e(cur)))
], {f: 0}));

console.log(
 execute(data)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to use `R.compose` or `R.pipe` to improve readability of `set_g(set_f(acc, set_e(cur)))` ? In real case, I have must more functions to apply, before and after set_f. Also, is there a way to avoid calling set_f multiple times ?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately set_f must depends on the previous iteration.

Comment: Actually the code doesn't work as intented: last iteration gives 330 but should be 333. Note: I have updated my example to reflect your code as there was a type in my initial post.

Comment: Actually, you should change your set_f from `const set_f = (acc, obj) =>  assoc('f', acc.e + obj.e, obj);` to `const set_f = (acc, obj) =>  assoc('f', acc.f + obj.e, obj);` and initial value from `{ e: 0 }` to `{f: 0}`. Maybe my phrasing was misleading to explain set_f, I have updated my initial post.